# ngrx observable timer angular 5

Tags: angular, ngrx

I am very much a newbie to angular and ngrx. I am building a pomodoro timer app that integrates with the Todoist api. I have used the the [ngrx/platform example app as a starter app] (https://github.com/ngrx/example-app) which uses containers with components. I originally created a timer in pure rxjs that functions as it should on it's own. I am currently trying to integrate the timer into my code from a taskDetail page that works in conjunction with a selected-task page. There is a play/pause button that should should behave with it's respective actions. The timer plays and pauses but the time remaining is not displaying correctly. I am assuming because i am not subscribing to the timer and/or passing to the time the way in which i should. The buttons all call the same function as output to selected-task-page.ts which has a provider of pomo-timer-service.ts

**task-detail.ts**

```
timeRemaining: any;
private timerSubscription: Subscription;

constructor(public pomoTimerService: PomoTimerService, private store: 
 Store<fromTasks.State>) {
 this.task$ = store.pipe(select(fromTasks.getSelectedTask));
 this.isSelectedTaskInCollection$ = store.pipe(
  select(fromTasks.isSelectedTaskInCollection)
 );
 this.timerSubscription = this.pomoTimerService.getState().subscribe(
  timeRemaining => {
    this.timeRemaining = timeRemaining;
   }
  );
}
```

```html
<button id="resume" name="resumeButton" class="resume-btn"
mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="resumeCommand($event)"><i class="material-icons">play_arrow</i></button>
<button id="pause" name="pauseButton" class="pause-btn"
mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="resumeCommand($event)"><i class="material-icons">pause</i></button>
```

The above template has as inputs and outputs the following:

```
@Input() timeRemaining: number;
@Input() timerSubscription: Subscription;
@Output() resumeClicked = new EventEmitter();


resumeCommand(action: any) {
 this.resumeClicked.emit(action);
 }
```

**Within my selected-task-page.ts template code I have:

```html
<bc-task-detail
  [timeRemaining]="this.pomoTimerService.timeRemaining"
  [pomoTitle]="this.pomoTimerService.pomoTitle$"
  [pomoCount]="this.pomoTimerService.pomoCount$"
  (resumeClicked)="resumeClicked($event)"
  (resumeClicked)="resumeClicked($event)">
 </bc-task-detail>
```

I have the following which then calls the service.**

```
(resumeClicked)="resumeClicked($event)"
(resumeClicked)="resumeClicked($event)"
```

**which calls:**

```
resumeClicked(event) {
 console.log(event);
 console.log(event.target);
 console.log(event.srcElement);
 console.log(event.type);
 console.log(event.currentTarget.attributes.name.nodeValue);
 console.log(event.currentTarget.attributes.id.nodeValue);
 this.pomoTimerService.startTimer(event);
 }
```

**Within my pomo-timer.ts I have the following**

```
private timerSource = new Subject<any>();
timeRemaining;

timer$ = this.timerSource.asObservable();

setState(state: any) {
 this.timerSource.next(state);
}

getState(): Observable<any> {
 return this.timerSource.asObservable();
}
```

Then i have the timer function in the pomo-timer.ts as well:

```
  startTimer(event) {
   this.buttonState = event.currentTarget.attributes.name.nodeValue;
   this.buttonAction = event.currentTarget.attributes.id.nodeValue;
   this.timerToggle = (this.buttonAction === 'resume') ? true : false;
   const resumeButton = document.getElementById('resume');
   const pauseButton = document.getElementById('pause');
   const resetButton = document.getElementById('reset');
   const interval$: any = interval(1000).pipe(mapTo(-1));
   const pause$ = fromEvent(pauseButton, 'click').pipe(mapTo(false));
   const resume$ = fromEvent(resumeButton, 'click').pipe(mapTo(true));

  const timer$ = merge(pause$, resume$).pipe(
   startWith(interval$),
   switchMap(val => (val ? interval$ : empty())),
   scan((acc, curr) => (curr ? curr + acc:acc),this.countdownSeconds$),
   takeWhile(v => v >= 0),
   )
   .subscribe(
     val => { this.timeRemaining = val; },
     () => {
     this.resetTimer();
    });
   }
```

The idea was that when the user clicks the play button the timer begins counting down and displaying the remaining time as it does so and when the pause button would pause it. One of my questions is should I be subscribing to timer$ or should I be subscribing to timerRemaining and then how do I subscribe to that so that it can go into the Input and display the remaining time as it is counting down and lastly do I even need to functions for getting and setting state?

I appreciate any help I can get. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you have a github repo this is pushed to? Would be easier to debug there or on stackblitz.

Comment: You don't have to use `this` in the template, just call the ts variables directly. For example change `[timeRemaining]="this.pomoTimerService.timeRemaining"` to `[timeRemaining]="pomoTimerService.timeRemaining"`.

Comment: Just pushed all changes to my repo: (https://github.com/djr-taureau/pomodoro-it). Forgive me, I am familiar with stackblitz but not sure how to upload my project into it.

Comment: Figured out how to upload from github to stackblitz easy enough. Here it is on stackblitz: (https://stackblitz.com/github/djr-taureau/pomodoro-it)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you could start / pause:

```
let defaultTime = 2;
let newTime;
let $interval;


const interval$ = Rx.Observable.timer(0, 1000).map(_ => {
  return _ <= defaultTime ? defaultTime - _ : $interval.unsubscribe();
});

function start() {
  $interval = interval$.subscribe(_ => {
    newTime = _;
    console.log(_);
  });
}

function pause() {
  $interval.unsubscribe();
  defaultTime = newTime - 1;
}

document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', start)
document.getElementById('btn2').addEventListener('click', pause)
```

[**DEMO**](https://rxjs-playground.github.io/#/?html=%3Cbutton%20id%3D%22btn%22%3EStart%3C%2Fbutton%3E%0A%3Cbutton%20id%3D%22btn2%22%3EPause%3C%2Fbutton%3E%0A&js=let%20defaultTime%20%3D%2010%3B%0Alet%20newTime%3B%0Alet%20%24interval%3B%0A%0A%0Aconst%20interval%24%20%3D%20Rx.Observable.timer%280%2C%201000%29.map%28_%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20return%20_%20%3C%3D%20defaultTime%20%3F%20defaultTime%20-%20_%20%3A%20%24interval.unsubscribe%28%29%3B%0A%7D%29%3B%0A%0Afunction%20start%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%24interval%20%3D%20interval%24.subscribe%28_%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20newTime%20%3D%20_%3B%0A%20%20%20%20console.log%28_%29%3B%0A%20%20%7D%29%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Afunction%20pause%28%29%20%7B%0A%20%20%24interval.unsubscribe%28%29%3B%0A%20%20defaultTime%20%3D%20newTime%20-%201%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A%0A%0Adocument.getElementById%28%27btn%27%29.addEventListener%28%27click%27%2C%20start%29%0Adocument.getElementById%28%27btn2%27%29.addEventListener%28%27click%27%2C%20pause%29)

Comment: Thank you for this very straightforward and simple solution to the timer @buzz  but I am still struggling to implement this correctly due to the interaction of the components. task-detail takes the button click as an output which passes to selected-task-page.ts which passes to the pomo-timer.ts (timer service) I put your code into the timer service and have it passing to a timer subscription which is received as input back to the original calling page, task-detail.ts but I can't get anything to output and I am not getting any errors